# Symfony class loader - usage? no examples of actual usage

Tags: php, symfony

I've been playing a bit with the Symfony class loader (read about others, the concept and started implementing).

I've read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html as well
I've changed the directories structure to fit and all. Here's a small source-code which fails:

Filename: test.php , dir: C:/test/BE/src/main.php

```
   <?php
    define('BASE_DIR','/../..');

    echo BASE_DIR.'/BE/libs/symphony/component/ClassLoader/2.1.0/UniversalClassLoader.php';
    require_once BASE_DIR.'/BE/libs/symphony/component/ClassLoader/2.1.0/UniversalClassLoader.php';

    use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

    $loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
    $loader->registerNamespace('App\Location\Location', 'Location/Location');

     // You can search the include_path as a last resort.
    $loader->useIncludePath(true);    
    $loader->register();
    use App\Location\Location;
    new App\Location\Location(); //Fatal error: Class 'App\Location\Location' not found in C:/test/BE/src/main.php
```

file name: Location.php , dir: C:/test/BE/src/Location/Location.php

```
namespace App\Location;

class Location{
    private $lat;
    private $lng;
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Which information are you missing from the docs in concrete? (Asking for docs is somewhat broad, other people are missing other information).

Comment: I've wrote it as a comment in the source: // Fatal error: Class 'Pimple' not found in ..path.. 
in the docs i'm missing the actual usage. Shoudl i do: use <classname> or straight ahead "new <classname>(<params>)". What if it's a static class, etc.. 
I agree, i wasn't clear about that. Despite i thought this kind of usage is trivial.

Comment: The use statement need to have the classname appended, I doubth that use \Pimple is correct, maybe use \Pimple\Pimple ?

Comment: ilanco: Fatal error: Class 'Pimple\Pimple' not found in ...it makes no sense to me to use Pimple\Pimple.
Also just to note: 
 Pimple is a DI Container(https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple), in pimple.php , its a regular "class Pimple implements ArrayAccess" , no namespacing or anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By registering your namespace as follows:

```
$loader->registerNamespace('App\Location\Location', 'Location/Location');
```

autoloader will look for the `App\Location\Location` class in the `Location/Location/App/Location/Location.php` file. Note that file/directory names are case sensitive.

First parameter of `registerNamespace()` is either a namespace or **part** of the namespace. Second parameter is a path to a PSR-0 compliant library. That means that directory structure inside that path should follow PSR-0 standard. This path **is not** used when calculating path for given namespace.

If you want to keep your current directory structure following code should work for you:

```
$loader->registerNamespace('App', __DIR__);
```

I'd rather put your source code in one common directory, for example src:

```
src/
  App/
    Location/
        Location.php
```

And then register namespaces as follows:

```
$loader->registerNamespace('App', 'src');
```

By doing that you're simply telling an autoloader that it should look for App namespaced classes in the src folder. Note that it will work for every class in the App namespace (following PSR-0).

Some time ago I wrote a blog post about the Symfony autoloader. You might find it helpful: [Autoloading classes in an any PHP project with Symfony2 ClassLoader component](http://www.zalas.eu/autoloading-classes-in-any-php-project-with-symfony2-classloader-component)

Since you plan to use Pimple and some of the Symfony components take a look at [Silex microframework](https://github.com/fabpot/silex). Might be it's something you need to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and constructive answer. Did just that. You've helped me understand what i did wrong, fix it and pointed me to further tools.

Comment: and BTW: you can load Pimple with Symfony autoloader just fine.

Comment: Tnx! How to do it properly ? :)

Answer (score 2):

You use:

```
$loader->registerNamespace('Pimple', BASE_DIR.'/BE/libs/Pimple/1.0.0/lib/Pimple');
```

To register the `Pimple` namespace for Pimple is useless, as Pimple is one class in the default namespace (it has no namespace).

The `UniversalClassLoader` does only work for PSR-0 and PEAR compatible directory layouts. If your layout is not, you should not expect it to work nor to be documented that it works for incompatbile layouts.

> *Explicit Note:*  **You are using the wrong tool to do the job**. All file layouts you have shared over the last hours are **incompatible** with `UniversalClassLoader`.

Apart from that if you give the wrong values for it's parameters, the class just won't work.

Comment: Either-way for using the auto-loader functionality, i'd prefer to have it all in the same way. It doesn't work for Pimple nor for: 

use \APP\Location\Location;
new \APP\Location\Location();
gives me:
Fatal error: Class 'APP\Location\Location'

Comment: I guess you do something wrong with the namespace understanding here. See https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/blob/master/UniversalClassLoader.php#L14 - Pimple is *not* PSR-0 *nor* PEAR compatible. Technically the `UniversalClassLoader` is the wrong class loader for that library.

Comment: I've went over the source a bit, but it didn't help me :/
I know pimple isn't PSR-0 compatible, as it isn't name spaced.. (it should be global), it's not an anti-pattern.

Either way, i did testing with the Location class, added a require to the path, worked. It's only: 
namespace App\Location;
class Location{ // implementation}
Simplest of classes...

Comment: Trying to say: nothing is solved, same problem. 
Location class is defined as required and still nothing.

Comment: If you know it isn't PSR-0 compatible why are you using the `UniversalClassloader` for Pimple, that makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not talking about Pimple, i'm talking about Location class. Not using Pimple.

Comment: @user1271518: Now you completely baffle me, in your question you pointed to `new Pimple(); // Fatal error: Class 'Pimple' not found in ..` when I asked about the error of your problem specifically.

Comment: Right, i got that same error for the Location class. After your comment, i'm commented the use of "Pimple" and changed 
use \Pimple;
new Pimple(); // Fatal error: Class 'Pimple' not found in ..
To: 
use App\Location\Location;
new App\Location\Location();

And i get the same error..

Comment: Please share the filename of the class in question and as well as the code within that file in question - add that to your question otherwise this can not be answered.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the mess, i've did the required changes. Hopefully now you'll see what is my problem.. Tnx!

Comment: -- update:
Solved the problem.
Created an "App" folder and moved the "Location" dir inside it.

I understand it's the "vendor" , but what if there's no need for that.. :/

Comment: @user1271518: Please get educated about PHP namespaces first (otherwise you won't understand the symfony documentation - which is *your problem*). See this line: `$loader->registerNamespace('App\Location\Location', 'Location/Location');` It's *wrong*. To my understanding of what you try to achieve, the correct variant should be: `$loader->registerNamespace('App\Location', 'fully/quallified/path/name/to/Location');` - and that's it.

Comment: Ok the 'Location/Location' is a qualified path . Inside Location i have also LocationDetails.php, that's the logical resouce name i've chosen. From what i've read in the Symphony doc. You can correct me if i'm wrong : 'App\Location\Location' is the explicit name-space reference (or sub-sub name space) and if i'll want LocationDetails.php which sitts in Location.php's same dir i can make: registerNamespace('App\Location\LocationDetails', 'Location/LocationDetails'); 

Explicitly or: 
make: registerNamespace('App\Location', 'Location/'); 
and then continue (it works, i've tested);

Comment: Short answer: No. Reason: Your direcotry layout with those class and file-names is *not* PSR-0 compatbible.  The loader class you use **Unified Class Loader** is for PSR-0 compatible or PEAR compatible layouts.